# Bad or good idea? WPF: Apply styles in code-behind programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, styles, code-behind

**SITUATION**

I am working on a (MVVM, Composite) WPF application, where everything should to be done in a very loosely coupled way.

When it comes to applying styles, I already have a nice little solution:

Each and every control, that is used, lives in an separate DLL, no matter if needs special styling or not.

In the constructor, each and every control, calls a static method, which delivers the *right* style for this control.

Example for a `TextBlock`:

```
public partial class TextBlock : System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
{
    public TextBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //The class ResourceCreator knows, which style to deliver
        this.Style = (System.Windows.Style)ResourceCreator.FindResourceByName(
            Styles.StyleNames.TextBlock);           
    }
}
```

This program design is okay so far because you never have to apply styles anywhere. The class `ResourceCreator` knows which style to apply to this control and of course it can switch between different styles. The control itself doesn't know, which style will be applied.

**WHAT I WANT**

In an MVVM application, a rule of thumb is, that there should be no logic at all in the code-behind of the View. Everything happens in the view model.

I want to break this rule only to apply styles. Any window or view should have one method in the code-behind, that iterates over the visual tree. Each detected control-type should be identified and then the appropriate style should be applied.

**QUESTION**

Is this a bad or good idea? Are there any facts, that I don't see, which are against this idea?

Comment: we often hear 'guidelines not rules'

Comment: When I work with WPF I often need to see structure of some custom control. I know that in my project I can go to the file with `ResourceDictionary` that is merged into a window resources. In this file Ctrl+F + <control_type> gives me style for desired control. Quick and simple. How easy is to see control's structure with your approach?

Comment: Also can you explain why you decided to go away from standard practice where all styles defined in `ResourceDictionary` that is merged into an app or window resources? **1)** It is loosely coupled (this is what so important for you); **2)** It doesn't require insert your magic string `ResourceCreator.FindResourceByName` in each control **3)** Styling by control's type is more safe than styling by some string constant (`StyleNames.TextBlock`).

Comment: @Maxim...In this case, different styles "themes" are living in different separate Dlls, which are part of the solution. So, I have to know which style I am looking for and look into this Dll.The idea is to have different Dlls, with different color themes and maybe different control behaviours. So I am able to switch between the "Theme Dlls". You are absolutley right when it comes to the magic strings. This will be changed to control-type. This was a bad design from the beginning. The overall reason is to switch instantly between different styles.

Comment: Sounds OK, your approach is possible. In our project for themes changing we use the way used in MahApps.Metro library: there are separate resource dictionaries for each theme and some `ThemeManager` which changes themes.

Comment: You could also have a theme with DynamicResource for colors and etc., and change it via Code behind for Theme purposes.

Comment: In reality, inside the code behind, this will be a "one-liner": ThemeManager.ApplyStyle(this). The ThemeManager will be injected by the UnityContainer into the views. I am sure, that it is possible. My hope was to gain insights, if this may lead to performance issues on views with a lot of controls. A disatvantage of course is, that you may not see the real design at design time until you start up, but I haven't tested it so far. I will post my solution when it's done. Happy to hear further insights.

Comment: MahApps.Metro approach works as you described, via `ThemeManager.ApplyStyle` and dynamic resources. But we placed this method call to behavior that attached to a window to eliminate repeating instructions in code-behind and do some additional actions. As for performance I didn't notice any problems, themes switching takes about half a second for most complex window in our project and I think this time is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In an MVVM application, a rule of thumb is, that there should be no logic at all in the code-behind of the View. Everything happens in the view model.

You are wrong. MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. It is about separation of concerns. It is perfectly fine to write any *view-related* code in the code-behind of the view.

And styles are purely view-related. So is any code that controls or interacts with the view layer that is difficult or inefficient to express in XAML, such as for example complex animations. These kind of things should *not* be implemented in the view model.

So you are not breaking any MVVM rules here :)

Your *application logic* should be implemented in the view model and your business logic should be implemented in the model. But any pure view-based functionality should be implemented in the view.

Comment: Thank you, mm8. I will mark this as a valid answer.